# How can I make a c# application outside of visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I'm very new to programming and I'm teaching myself. I made a calculator for some calculations we do in the lab I work in and wanted to be able to open the app from the computer at work instead of opening it on visual studio from my laptop. Just curious if this is possible, and I've been trying to Google if this is possible but I don't think I'm using the right words in my searches.

If this is possible, it'd be awesome if someone could help me out with an explanation or a link to a video or thread that already explains this.

Thank you for your time!!

Comment: You want to _compile_ your app and copy the compiled exe file to your computer at work.  The easiest way is to click the play button and then copy the files from the bin folder.

Comment: That is almost the whole purpose of development using an IDE, like Visual Studio,, it is to help you *create* the application. You should not rely on an IDE to *run* your application after development has been "completed" (completed in quotes because an application is not truly ever completed).

Comment: Hi, I think what you need is to create an .exe, in order to perform this, visual studio has a tool called OneClick. What you need is to take the exe and pass it to the PC where you want to use the calculator. If is nothing complex what you have, you can use the autogenerated exe file, which you can find in Debug folder. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm super sorry. I should have mentioned I'm using the visual basic for mac operating systems. I'm trying to follow along with the instructions in the answer, but I think I'm getting lost in the different interface.

Answer (score 3):

1. In Visual Studio to the left of the Start button (at the top) there's two
   dropdowns, switch the one on the left from `Debug` to `Release` - this allows the
   compiler to make optimizations when building the program.
2. In the toolbar, click `Build` -> `Build Solution`
3. Navigate to the directory of your project in Windows explorer (you can right click the Project name in the Solution Explorer on the right in Visual Studio, then click `Open Folder in File Explorer` as a shortcut - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppma8.png)), you should see a `bin` folder. Navigate to `bin\Release\`.
4. Copy everything in that folder to wherever you'd like to run the
   program from, and you can start it via the exe.

Comment: There are some assumptions being made here like this is not a web hosted application, that the platform is compatible (.net standard can create apps for platforms other than windows), that the same version of the .net framework has been deployed on the target machine, access rights on the target machine, and also external dependencies that might need to be deployed. That said we can probably assume that the calculator app is probably basic enough that you do  not have to worry about this stuff but that is also an assumption.

Comment: Absolutely. I believe even programs written in .NET Core also have a different output directory structure. But this'll be the standard workflow for basic console/win forms/wpf apps.